# Canvas linear gradient taking the value of another input type color field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

So I have this simple image editor where I'm using a canvas to draw in a user-selected image and some texts. That is the user can upload an image and then if they want they can add texts or just change the gradient of the image.

Right now the app works perfectly fine except there is one issue.

How to find the issue? Do the following:

1. Upload a random image.
2. Choose a color from `Text 2 Shadow Offset X` Color Picker.
3. Increase the slider beside the `Text 2 Shadow Offset X` Color Picker.
4. Then increase the slider of `Image Gradient and Opacity`.

The image will have a gradient and take the value of the `Text 2 Shadow Offset X` Color Picker instead of `Image Gradient and Opacity` Color Picker which has default black color.

This is the code:

```js
const canvasTxt                 = window.canvasTxt.default;
const canvas                    = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx                       = canvas?.getContext('2d');
const btnDownload               = document.querySelector('.btnDownload');
const fileUpload                = document.querySelector('.file-upload');

const text1                     = document.getElementById('text1');
const textForm1                 = document.getElementById('text1-form');
const text2                     = document.getElementById('text2');
const textForm2                 = document.getElementById('text2-form');
const text2ShadowColor          = document.getElementById('text2shadowcolor');
const text2ShadowOffsetY        = document.getElementById('text2shadowoffy');

const imageForm                 = document.getElementById('image-form');
const imageGrad                 = document.getElementById('gradientcolor');
const imageGradOpacity          = document.getElementById('gradientopacity');


$(fileUpload).on('change', function(e) {
      let imgObj          = new Image();
      imgObj.onload       = draw;
      imgObj.onerror      = failed;
      imgObj.src          = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

      imgManipulation( e, imgObj );
});    

const imgManipulation = ( e, imgObj ) => {
    $(textForm1).on('change keyup input', updateCanvas);
    $(textForm2).on('change keyup input', updateCanvas);
    $(imageForm).on('change keyup input', updateCanvas);

    function updateCanvas(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);

        createGradient($(imageGrad).val(), $(imageGradOpacity).val());

  
        // TEXT1 STYLES based on user input
        canvasTxt.fontSize      = 30;
        canvasTxt.drawText(
            ctx, 
            $(text1).val(), 
            0, 
            0, 
            200, 
            200
        );


        // TEXT2 STYLES
        canvasTxt.font          = 20;

        canvasTxt.drawText(
            ctx, 
            $(text2).val(),
            20, 
            20, 
            200, 
            200
        );
    }
};

function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
};

function createGradient(hex, alpha) {

    const r = hexToRgb(hex).r.toString();
    const g = hexToRgb(hex).g.toString();
    const b = hexToRgb(hex).b.toString();

    var gradient =  ctx.createLinearGradient(800, 0, 0, 0);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${alpha})`);

    ctx.save() // <----------- ADD
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.restore() // <----------- ADD
};


function draw() {
    canvas.width        = this.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height       = this.naturalHeight;
    const nw            = this.naturalWidth;
    const nh            = this.naturalHeight;

    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, nw, nh);
};

function failed() {
    console.error("The provided file couldn't be loaded as an Image media");
};


$(btnDownload).on('click', function(e) {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    a.download = "canvas-image.png";
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
});
```

```css
#canvas{
    background-color: transparent; 
    width: 30%; 
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/canvas-txt@3.0.0/build/index.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>

<div>
    <input type="file" class="file-upload" />
    <button class="btnDownload">Download</button>
</div>


<div>
  <form id="text1-form">
    <input type="text" id="text1" placeholder="text 1"/> 
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <form id="text2-form">
    <input type="text" id="text2" placeholder="text 2"/> 
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Image Gradient and Opacity</h2>
  <form id="image-form">
    <input type="color" id="gradientcolor" value="#000000" />
    <input type="range" id="gradientopacity" min="0" max="1" value="0" step="0.05" />
  </form>
</div>


<div>
  <h2>Text2 Shadow Offset X</h2>
  <input type="color" id="text2shadowcolor" value="#000000" />
  <input type="range" id="text2shadowoffy" min="0" max="40" value="0" />
</div>
```

Rundown of the code:

1: First I have the `fileUpload` event listener. It takes in an image from the user and creates an image object and draws it on the canvas. Then `imgManipulation` function is called with the `imgObj` and `event` as its arguments.

2. The `imgManipulation` function starts off with the `input` event listeners for the texts. That is whenever there is a change in the input, that is a user writes something, `updateCanvas` function is called.
3. The `updateCanvas` function actually draws the texts on the image. I'm using a package called `canvasTxt` which helps the text to be multiline.
4. The `createGradient` function call inside `updateCanvas` is the image gradient for the image.

I tried moving the createGradient function call below the drawTexts but then the gradient comes to the top of everything. The texts become darker too.

How can I make the gradient take it's value only instead of shadow color?

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shadowColor` still work when drawing 'Gradient' next time.
Add `ctx.save()` before, and `ctx.restore()` after.

```js
const canvasTxt                 = window.canvasTxt.default;
const canvas                    = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx                       = canvas?.getContext('2d');
const btnDownload               = document.querySelector('.btnDownload');
const fileUpload                = document.querySelector('.file-upload');

const text1                     = document.getElementById('text1');
const textForm1                 = document.getElementById('text1-form');
const text2                     = document.getElementById('text2');
const textForm2                 = document.getElementById('text2-form');
const text2ShadowColor          = document.getElementById('text2shadowcolor');
const text2ShadowOffsetY        = document.getElementById('text2shadowoffy');

const imageForm                 = document.getElementById('image-form');
const imageGrad                 = document.getElementById('gradientcolor');
const imageGradOpacity          = document.getElementById('gradientopacity');


$(fileUpload).on('change', function(e) {
      let imgObj          = new Image();
      imgObj.onload       = draw;
      imgObj.onerror      = failed;
      imgObj.src          = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

      imgManipulation( e, imgObj );
});    

const imgManipulation = ( e, imgObj ) => {
    $(textForm1).on('change keyup input', updateCanvas);
    $(textForm2).on('change keyup input', updateCanvas);
    $(imageForm).on('change keyup input', updateCanvas);

    function updateCanvas() {
        e.preventDefault();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);

        createGradient($(imageGrad).val(), $(imageGradOpacity).val());

  
        // TEXT1 STYLES based on user input
        canvasTxt.fontSize      = 30;
        canvasTxt.drawText(
            ctx, 
            $(text1).val(), 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0
        );


        // TEXT2 STYLES
        ctx.save() // <----------- ADD
        ctx.shadowColor         = $(text2ShadowColor).val();
        ctx.shadowOffsetY       = $(text2ShadowOffsetY).val();
        canvasTxt.font          = 20;

        canvasTxt.drawText(
            ctx, 
            $(text2).val(),
            20, 
            20, 
            0, 
            0
        );
        ctx.restore() // <----------- ADD
    }
};

function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
};

function createGradient(hex, alpha) {

    const r = hexToRgb(hex).r.toString();
    const g = hexToRgb(hex).g.toString();
    const b = hexToRgb(hex).b.toString();

    var gradient =  ctx.createLinearGradient(800, 0, 0, 0);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${alpha})`);

    ctx.save() // <----------- ADD
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.restore() // <----------- ADD
};


function draw() {
    canvas.width        = this.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height       = this.naturalHeight;
    const nw            = this.naturalWidth;
    const nh            = this.naturalHeight;

    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, nw, nh);
};

function failed() {
    console.error("The provided file couldn't be loaded as an Image media");
};


$(btnDownload).on('click', function(e) {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    a.download = "canvas-image.png";
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
});
```

```css
#canvas{
    background-color: transparent; 
    width: 30%; 
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/canvas-txt@3.0.0/build/index.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>

<div>
    <input type="file" class="file-upload" />
    <button class="btnDownload">Download</button>
</div>


<div>
  <form id="text1-form">
    <input type="text" id="text1" placeholder="text 1"/> 
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <form id="text2-form">
    <input type="text" id="text2" placeholder="text 2"/> 
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Image Gradient and Opacity</h2>
  <form id="image-form">
    <input type="color" id="gradientcolor" value="#000000" />
    <input type="range" id="gradientopacity" min="0" max="1" value="0" step="0.05" />
  </form>
</div>


<div>
  <h2>Text2 Shadow Offset X</h2>
  <input type="color" id="text2shadowcolor" value="#000000" />
  <input type="range" id="text2shadowoffy" min="0" max="40" value="0" />
</div>
```

Comment: hey man, sorry to bother you. But I need another help based on this canvas. Right now if I upload an image and write something on it, it works fine. But if I want to change the image then the previously written text disappears. How can I keep the text on top and be able to change the image as many times as I want?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66611694/html5-canvas-text-drawn-on-image-stops-showing-when-image-is-changed

Answer (score 1):

This is because since you didn't reset the shadow options, the gradient itself is affected by the shadowing, just like it would be affected by a filter if it makes things clearer to you:

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
// a vertical green to transparent gradient
const grad = ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createLinearGradient( 0, 0, 0, 150 );
grad.addColorStop( 0, "rgba(0,255,0)" );
grad.addColorStop( 1, "rgba(0,255,0,0.01)" );
ctx.textAlign = "center";

ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, 50, 150 );

ctx.filter = "sepia(1)";
ctx.fillRect( 75, 0, 50, 150 );

ctx.filter = "invert(1)";
ctx.fillRect( 150, 0, 50, 150 );

ctx.filter = "none"; // disable filtering

ctx.shadowColor = "red";
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 15;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 25;
ctx.fillRect( 225, 0, 50, 150 );

// disable shadows
ctx.shadowColor = "transparent";
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;

ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillText( "sepia(1)", 100, 20 );
ctx.fillText( "none", 25, 20 ); 
ctx.fillText( "invert(1)", 175, 20 );
ctx.fillText( "shadow", 250, 20 );
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500"></canvas>
```

As you can see, because your gradient is not fully opaque, the shadow is visible behind it, and the rendered color is altered.

To workaround that, you can simply do as I did in my example:

```
// disable shadows
ctx.shadowColor = "transparent";
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
```

```js
const canvasTxt                 = window.canvasTxt.default;
const canvas                    = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx                       = canvas?.getContext('2d');
const btnDownload               = document.querySelector('.btnDownload');
const fileUpload                = document.querySelector('.file-upload');

const text1                     = document.getElementById('text1');
const textForm1                 = document.getElementById('text1-form');
const text2                     = document.getElementById('text2');
const textForm2                 = document.getElementById('text2-form');
const text2ShadowColor          = document.getElementById('text2shadowcolor');
const text2ShadowOffsetY        = document.getElementById('text2shadowoffy');

const imageForm                 = document.getElementById('image-form');
const imageGrad                 = document.getElementById('gradientcolor');
const imageGradOpacity          = document.getElementById('gradientopacity');


$(fileUpload).on('change', function(e) {
      let imgObj          = new Image();
      imgObj.onload       = draw;
      imgObj.onerror      = failed;
      imgObj.src          = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

      imgManipulation( e, imgObj );
});    

const imgManipulation = ( e, imgObj ) => {
    $(textForm1).on('change keyup input', updateCanvas);
    $(textForm2).on('change keyup input', updateCanvas);
    $(imageForm).on('change keyup input', updateCanvas);

    function updateCanvas() {
        e.preventDefault();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);

        createGradient($(imageGrad).val(), $(imageGradOpacity).val());

  
        // TEXT1 STYLES based on user input
        canvasTxt.fontSize      = 30;
        canvasTxt.drawText(
            ctx, 
            $(text1).val(), 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0
        );


        // TEXT2 STYLES
        ctx.shadowColor         = $(text2ShadowColor).val();
        ctx.shadowOffsetY       = $(text2ShadowOffsetY).val();
        canvasTxt.font          = 20;

        canvasTxt.drawText(
            ctx, 
            $(text2).val(),
            20, 
            20, 
            0, 
            0
        );

        // clean behind
        ctx.shadowColor         = "transparent";
        ctx.shadowOffsetY       = 0;

    }
};

function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
};

function createGradient(hex, alpha) {

    const r = hexToRgb(hex).r.toString();
    const g = hexToRgb(hex).g.toString();
    const b = hexToRgb(hex).b.toString();

    var gradient =  ctx.createLinearGradient(800, 0, 0, 0);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${alpha})`);

    const current_fill_style = ctx.fillStyle;
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // clean behind
    ctx.fillStyle = current_fill_style;
};


function draw() {
    canvas.width        = this.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height       = this.naturalHeight;
    const nw            = this.naturalWidth;
    const nh            = this.naturalHeight;

    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, nw, nh);
};

function failed() {
    console.error("The provided file couldn't be loaded as an Image media");
};


$(btnDownload).on('click', function(e) {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    a.download = "canvas-image.png";
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
});
```

```css
#canvas{
    background-color: transparent; 
    width: 30%; 
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/canvas-txt@3.0.0/build/index.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>

<div>
    <input type="file" class="file-upload" />
    <button class="btnDownload">Download</button>
</div>


<div>
  <form id="text1-form">
    <input type="text" id="text1" placeholder="text 1"/> 
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <form id="text2-form">
    <input type="text" id="text2" placeholder="text 2"/> 
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Image Gradient and Opacity</h2>
  <form id="image-form">
    <input type="color" id="gradientcolor" value="#000000" />
    <input type="range" id="gradientopacity" min="0" max="1" value="0" step="0.05" />
  </form>
</div>


<div>
  <h2>Text2 Shadow Offset X</h2>
  <input type="color" id="text2shadowcolor" value="#000000" />
  <input type="range" id="text2shadowoffy" min="0" max="40" value="0" />
</div>
```

Comment: hey man, sorry to bother you. But I need another help based on this canvas. Right now if I upload an image and write something on it, it works fine. But if I want to change the image then the previously written text disappears. How can I keep the text on top and be able to change the image as many times as I want?