# HTML5 Canvas: Text drawn on image stops showing when image is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, html5-canvas

So I have this simple image editor where I'm using a canvas to draw in a user-selected image and some texts. That is, the user can upload an image and then if they want they can add texts or just change the gradient of the image.

Right now the app works perfectly fine except there is one issue.

How to find the issue? Do the following:

1. Upload a random image.
2. Type something in the input fields.
3. Upload and change the image.

You will see that the text disappears.

This is the code:

```js
const canvasTxt                 = window.canvasTxt.default;
const canvas                    = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx                       = canvas?.getContext('2d');
const btnDownload               = document.querySelector('.btnDownload');
const fileUpload                = document.querySelector('.file-upload');

const text1                     = document.getElementById('text1');
const textForm1                 = document.getElementById('text1-form');
const text2                     = document.getElementById('text2');
const textForm2                 = document.getElementById('text2-form');
const text2ShadowColor          = document.getElementById('text2shadowcolor');
const text2ShadowOffsetY        = document.getElementById('text2shadowoffy');

const imageForm                 = document.getElementById('image-form');
const imageGrad                 = document.getElementById('gradientcolor');
const imageGradOpacity          = document.getElementById('gradientopacity');


$(fileUpload).on('change', function(e) {
      let imgObj          = new Image();
      imgObj.onload       = draw;
      imgObj.onerror      = failed;
      imgObj.src          = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

      imgManipulation( e, imgObj );
});    

const imgManipulation = ( e, imgObj ) => {
    $(textForm1).on('change keyup input', updateCanvas);
    $(textForm2).on('change keyup input', updateCanvas);
    $(imageForm).on('change keyup input', updateCanvas);

    function updateCanvas(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);

        createGradient($(imageGrad).val(), $(imageGradOpacity).val());

  
        // TEXT1 STYLES based on user input
        canvasTxt.fontSize      = 70;
        ctx.fillStyle           = "white";
        canvasTxt.drawText(
            ctx, 
            $(text1).val(), 
            0, 
            0, 
            200, 
            200
        );


        // TEXT2 STYLES
        canvasTxt.font          = 50;
        ctx.fillStyle           = "white";
        canvasTxt.drawText(
            ctx, 
            $(text2).val(),
            20, 
            20, 
            200, 
            200
        );
    }
};

function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
};

function createGradient(hex, alpha) {

    const r = hexToRgb(hex).r.toString();
    const g = hexToRgb(hex).g.toString();
    const b = hexToRgb(hex).b.toString();

    var gradient =  ctx.createLinearGradient(800, 0, 0, 0);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${alpha})`);

    ctx.save() // <----------- ADD
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.restore() // <----------- ADD
};


function draw() {
    canvas.width        = this.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height       = this.naturalHeight;
    const nw            = this.naturalWidth;
    const nh            = this.naturalHeight;

    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, nw, nh);
};

function failed() {
    console.error("The provided file couldn't be loaded as an Image media");
};


$(btnDownload).on('click', function(e) {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    a.download = "canvas-image.png";
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
});
```

```css
#canvas{
    background-color: transparent; 
    width: 30%; 
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/canvas-txt@3.0.0/build/index.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>

<div>
    <input type="file" class="file-upload" />
    <button class="btnDownload">Download</button>
</div>


<div>
  <form id="text1-form">
    <input type="text" id="text1" placeholder="text 1"/> 
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <form id="text2-form">
    <input type="text" id="text2" placeholder="text 2"/> 
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Image Gradient and Opacity</h2>
  <form id="image-form">
    <input type="color" id="gradientcolor" value="#000000" />
    <input type="range" id="gradientopacity" min="0" max="1" value="0" step="0.05" />
  </form>
</div>


<div>
  <h2>Text2 Shadow Offset X</h2>
  <input type="color" id="text2shadowcolor" value="#000000" />
  <input type="range" id="text2shadowoffy" min="0" max="40" value="0" />
</div>
```

Rundown of the code:

1: First I have the fileUpload event listener. It takes in an image from the user and creates an image object and draws it on the canvas. Then imgManipulation function is called with the imgObj and event as its arguments.

The imgManipulation function starts off with the input event listeners for the texts. That is whenever there is a change in the input, that is a user writes something, updateCanvas function is called.

The updateCanvas function actually draws the texts on the image. I'm using a package called canvasTxt which helps the text to be multiline.

After changing the image, the text magically appears if the user writes a letter on the input field where there is previously typed user text.

How can I change the image without removing the text typed by the user?

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can see there are two ways to draw image: `imgObj.onload = draw;` and `updateCanvas`.

So when change the image, `draw` function called without filling text.

It's better to put the drawing things of the canvas in the same function.

Like this.

```js
const canvasTxt                 = window.canvasTxt.default;
const canvas                    = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx                       = canvas?.getContext('2d');
const btnDownload               = document.querySelector('.btnDownload');
const fileUpload                = document.querySelector('.file-upload');

const text1                     = document.getElementById('text1');
const textForm1                 = document.getElementById('text1-form');
const text2                     = document.getElementById('text2');
const textForm2                 = document.getElementById('text2-form');
const text2ShadowColor          = document.getElementById('text2shadowcolor');
const text2ShadowOffsetY        = document.getElementById('text2shadowoffy');

const imageForm                 = document.getElementById('image-form');
const imageGrad                 = document.getElementById('gradientcolor');
const imageGradOpacity          = document.getElementById('gradientopacity');


$(fileUpload).on('change', function(e) {
      let imgObj          = new Image();
      imgObj.onload       = draw;
      imgObj.onerror      = failed;
      imgObj.src          = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

      imgManipulation( e, imgObj );
});  

// -----AND `reDraw` function
function reDraw (imgObj) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);

        createGradient($(imageGrad).val(), $(imageGradOpacity).val());

  
        // TEXT1 STYLES based on user input
        canvasTxt.fontSize      = 70;
        ctx.fillStyle           = "white";
        canvasTxt.drawText(
            ctx, 
            $(text1).val(), 
            0, 
            0, 
            200, 
            200
        );


        // TEXT2 STYLES 
        canvasTxt.fontSize      = 50; // canvasTxt.font = 50;
        ctx.fillStyle           = "white";
        canvasTxt.drawText(
            ctx, 
            $(text2).val(),
            20, 
            20, 
            200, 
            200
        );
}

const imgManipulation = ( e, imgObj ) => {
    $(textForm1).on('change keyup input', updateCanvas);
    $(textForm2).on('change keyup input', updateCanvas);
    $(imageForm).on('change keyup input', updateCanvas);

    function updateCanvas(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        reDraw(imgObj) // <-------- CALL `reDraw`
    }
};

function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
};

function createGradient(hex, alpha) {

    const r = hexToRgb(hex).r.toString();
    const g = hexToRgb(hex).g.toString();
    const b = hexToRgb(hex).b.toString();

    var gradient =  ctx.createLinearGradient(800, 0, 0, 0);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${alpha})`);

    ctx.save()
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.restore()
};


function draw() {
    canvas.width        = this.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height       = this.naturalHeight;
    // const nw            = this.naturalWidth;
    // const nh            = this.naturalHeight;

    // ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, nw, nh);
    reDraw(this) // <-------- CALL `reDraw`
};

function failed() {
    console.error("The provided file couldn't be loaded as an Image media");
};


$(btnDownload).on('click', function(e) {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    a.download = "canvas-image.png";
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
});
```

```css
#canvas{
  background-color: transparent; 
  width: 30%; 
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/canvas-txt@3.0.0/build/index.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>

<div>
    <input type="file" class="file-upload" />
    <button class="btnDownload">Download</button>
</div>


<div>
  <form id="text1-form">
    <input type="text" id="text1" placeholder="text 1"/> 
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <form id="text2-form">
    <input type="text" id="text2" placeholder="text 2"/> 
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Image Gradient and Opacity</h2>
  <form id="image-form">
    <input type="color" id="gradientcolor" value="#000000" />
    <input type="range" id="gradientopacity" min="0" max="1" value="0" step="0.05" />
  </form>
</div>


<div>
  <h2>Text2 Shadow Offset X</h2>
  <input type="color" id="text2shadowcolor" value="#000000" />
  <input type="range" id="text2shadowoffy" min="0" max="40" value="0" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a timing problem.

In this code:

```
$(fileUpload).on('change', function(e) {
      let imgObj          = new Image();
      imgObj.onload       = draw;
      imgObj.onerror      = failed;
      imgObj.src          = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

      imgManipulation( e, imgObj );
});
```

you ask that when the image is loaded the draw function be performed. You then call imgManipulation, which would correctly draw the text but this is called immediately, before the image has had a chance to load. So it writes the text (which is still saved in the input element) but this then gets overwritten when the image is loaded and draw is called.

As draw just writes the image to the canvas with most images this is going to overwrite the top part of the canvas which contains the text.

So, on a new image being loaded you need to update the whole canvas, including the text.

Note: a new img element is created each time the user selects a new image. It would probably be wise to have just one image element and give that the new source, otherwise a long user session could fill up store needlessly.

This snippet illustrates the timing problem by setting a timeout when a new image is being loaded and calling for an update of the canvas when that has happened. Obviously for a production version it would be sensible to refactor the code so that the updating happened on an image being loaded (or already loaded).

There was a further problem in the setting of fontSize for text2 which tried to set font as 50 - this affected the fontsize used on subsequent redraws so it has been altered to fontSize. Text2 also overwrites part of text1, but that's a different question.

```js
        const canvasTxt                 = window.canvasTxt.default;
    const canvas                    = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const ctx                       = canvas?.getContext('2d');
    const btnDownload               = document.querySelector('.btnDownload');
    const fileUpload                = document.querySelector('.file-upload');

    const text1                     = document.getElementById('text1');
    const textForm1                 = document.getElementById('text1-form');
    const text2                     = document.getElementById('text2');
    const textForm2                 = document.getElementById('text2-form');
    const text2ShadowColor          = document.getElementById('text2shadowcolor');
    const text2ShadowOffsetY        = document.getElementById('text2shadowoffy');

    const imageForm                 = document.getElementById('image-form');
    const imageGrad                 = document.getElementById('gradientcolor');
    const imageGradOpacity          = document.getElementById('gradientopacity');

          let imgObj          = new Image();

    $(fileUpload).on('change', function(e) {
          imgObj.onload       = draw;
          imgObj.onerror      = failed;
          imgObj.src          = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

          setTimeout(function() {imgManipulation(e, imgObj);}, 1000);// timeout set just to illustrate the timing problem (1sec = long enough for img to load normally)
          //imgManipulation( e, imgObj );
    });    

    const imgManipulation = ( e, imgObj ) => {
        $(textForm1).on('change keyup input', updateCanvas);
        $(textForm2).on('change keyup input', updateCanvas);
        $(imageForm).on('change keyup input', updateCanvas);
        updateCanvas(e);// force an update of canvas each time called, not just on keyups
        function updateCanvas(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);

            createGradient($(imageGrad).val(), $(imageGradOpacity).val());

      
            // TEXT1 STYLES based on user input
            canvasTxt.fontSize      = 70;
            ctx.fillStyle           = "white";
            canvasTxt.drawText(
                ctx, 
                $(text1).val(), 
                0, 
                0, 
                200, 
                200
            );


            // TEXT2 STYLES
            canvasTxt.fontSize          = 50;//was just 'font'
            ctx.fillStyle           = "white";
            canvasTxt.drawText(
                ctx, 
                $(text2).val(),
                20, 
                20, 
                200, 
                200
            );
        }
    };

    function hexToRgb(hex) {
        var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
        return result ? {
            r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
            g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
            b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
        } : null;
    };

    function createGradient(hex, alpha) {

        const r = hexToRgb(hex).r.toString();
        const g = hexToRgb(hex).g.toString();
        const b = hexToRgb(hex).b.toString();

        var gradient =  ctx.createLinearGradient(800, 0, 0, 0);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${alpha})`);

        ctx.save() // <----------- ADD
        ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.restore() // <----------- ADD
    };


    function draw() {
        canvas.width        = this.naturalWidth;
        canvas.height       = this.naturalHeight;
        const nw            = this.naturalWidth;
        const nh            = this.naturalHeight;

        //ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, nw, nh);
    };

    function failed() {
        console.error("The provided file couldn't be loaded as an Image media");
    };


    $(btnDownload).on('click', function(e) {
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL();
        a.download = "canvas-image.png";
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    });
```

```css
#canvas{
        background-color: transparent; 
        width: 30%; 
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid #777;
    }
</style>
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/canvas-txt@3.0.0/build/index.js"></script>
    
  <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>

    <div>
        <input type="file" class="file-upload" />
        <button class="btnDownload">Download</button>
    </div>


    <div>
      <form id="text1-form">
        <input type="text" id="text1" placeholder="text 1"/> 
      </form>
    </div>

    <div>
      <form id="text2-form">
        <input type="text" id="text2" placeholder="text 2"/> 
      </form>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h2>Image Gradient and Opacity</h2>
      <form id="image-form">
        <input type="color" id="gradientcolor" value="#000000" />
        <input type="range" id="gradientopacity" min="0" max="1" value="0" step="0.05" />
      </form>
    </div>


    <div>
      <h2>Text2 Shadow Offset X</h2>
      <input type="color" id="text2shadowcolor" value="#000000" />
      <input type="range" id="text2shadowoffy" min="0" max="40" value="0" />
    </div>
```